# How can I add a function to FactoryBot globally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I have a class that extends FactoryBot to include functionality to copy Rails' `.first_or_create`.

```
module FactoryBotFirstOrCreate
  def first(type, args)
    klass = type.to_s.camelize.constantize

    conditions = args.first.is_a?(Symbol) ? args[1] : args[0]

    if !conditions.empty? && conditions.is_a?(Hash)
      klass.where(conditions).first
    end
  end

  def first_or_create(type, *args)
    first(type, args) || create(type, *args)
  end

  def first_or_build(type, *args)
    first(type, args) || build(type, *args)
  end
end
```

I can add that to the `SyntaxRunner` class

```
module FactoryBot
  class SyntaxRunner
    include FactoryBotFirstOrCreate
  end
end
```

to access it in factories

```
# ...
after(:create) do |thing, evaluator|
  first_or_create(:other_thing, thing: thing)
end
```

But when I attempt to employ this outside of factories, I can't access it...

- `FactoryBot::SyntaxRunner.first_or_create` or `FactoryBot.first_or_create` doesn't help
- `include`ing it in the FactoryBot module doesn't help
- `config.include` in `RSpec.configure` doesn't help
- I can't even access it directly `FactoryBot::SyntaxHelper.first_or_create`

With all of those steps in place, I still get `NoMethodError: undefined method first_or_create`

What can I include or otherwise configure to allow this method to be as accessible to me as FactoryGirl's `create`?

Comment: You could `extend` the `FactoryBot` module e.g. `module FactoryBot; extend FactoryBotFirstOrCreate; end` then `FactoryBot.first_or_create` will work. However I do not guarantee the rest of the methods are accessible in that context (didn't really look into it at all)

Comment: When running a spec why don't you know if a record exists or not? Why do you need this method. It feels to me like your specs do not run in isolation.

Comment: Thanks @engineersmnky -- that worked. If you submit an answer, I'll gladly accept.

Comment: @spickermann's comment is bang-on, too, I'd take it into consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @engineersmnky, `extend`ing FactoryBot works

```rb
module FactoryBot
  extend FactoryBotFirstOrCreate
end
```

then this works

```rb
my_foo = first_or_create(:everything, is: :awesome, if_we: :work_together)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in an initializer file:

```rb
module SystemRecords
  def system_authentication_user
    AuthenticationUser.system
  end

  def system_platform_tenant
    PlatformTenant.system
  end

  def system_user_profile
    UserProfile.admin_role
  end

  def system_user
    User.system
  end
end

module FactoryBot
  class SyntaxRunner
    include SystemRecords
  end
end
```

I could now do:

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :some_record, class: SomeClass do
    platform_tenant { system_platform_tenant }
    created_by { system_user_profile }
    updated_by { created_by }
    authentication_user { system_authentication_user }
  end
end
```