# How to add first_or_create method to factory_bot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I would like to use the factory file in db/seed.rb with idempotency

Then I searched and found the following information.

[How can I add a function to FactoryBot globally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52385642/how-can-i-add-a-function-to-factorybot-globally)

According to the information of the link, it seems that the first_or_create method can be added by extending the customized module

But I don't know where the factorybot module is.
To insert a customized module to factorybot that gem installed with rails
Where to extend?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [example](https://travisofthenorth.com/blog/2016/7/30/factorygirl-first-or-create) of how to do this. 
I hope this solves your problem. Make sure there is no other way to do it because FactoryGirl doesn't have a feature like this for a reason.